# Orthogonal subspace of an orthogonal subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{F}(\mathbb{C}\ or\ \mathbb{R})$, and let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. Assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional, I have proved that $(W^{\perp})^{\perp} = W$ using some dimension considerations.

Is this also true for an infinite-dimensional space?

Comment: Inner product can be defined in infinite-dimensional space.

Comment: No, for instance if $W$ is dense, then $W^{\perp} = \{0\}$. For instance, take $c_{00} \subset \ell^2$.

Answer (score 2):

As Prahlad Vaidyanathan stated, this is, in general, not true. However, it is true that $W\subseteq (W^\perp)^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

In general you have $W^{\bot \bot} = \overline{\operatorname{sp} W}$.

For a simple example, take $l_2$ and let $W =\operatorname{sp} \{e_k \}$, a proper dense subspace of $l_2$.
Then $W^\bot = \{0\}$ and so $W^{\bot \bot} = l_2$.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to note that if $V=W\oplus W^\perp$ (which is necessary true if $W$ is finite dimensional and, in particular, if $V$ is finite dimensional), we have $(W^\perp)^\perp=W$.

To prove this, we only have to check that $(W^\perp)^\perp\subset W$, since the reverse inclusion is true in general (that is, without any assumption on $W$ and even if $W$ is not a subspace of $V$).

Let $x\in W^\perp$. There exists $a\in W$ and $b\in W^\perp$ such that $x=a+b$. By difference : $a=x-b\in W^\perp$, hence $a\in W\cap W^\perp$, so that $a=0$. This proves that $x\in W$.